# I see only DHCP requests but not DHCP responses from "parallel" computer

Tags: ethernet, dhcp, tcpdump

I have two Raspberry Pies and one DHCP server connected to a switch. Raspi #2 is configured to do netboot.

[image]

I am sitting on Raspi #1 and doing

```
tcpdump 'ether host b8:27:eb:5d:4a:f6' -p -i eth0 -vv
```

I am also sitting on DHCP server and doing

```
tcpdump 'ether host b8:27:eb:5d:4a:f6' -p -i igc2 -vv
```

`eth0` and `igc2` are network interface names on respective devices.

When I turn Raspi #2 on, I am seeing it's DHCP requests, but I don't see DHCP server responses when sitting on Raspi #1.

When I sit on DHCP server itself, I see both requests and responses.

Why?

Does my switch filter packets? Why do I see other traffic then?

Answer (score 2):

In DORA exchange client sends out Discover and Request -packets, server responds with Offer and ACK. Client's (Raspi #2) D and R are sent with destination MAC `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` i.e. broadcast MAC. Server's O and A are sent with destination MAC `b8:27:eb:5d:4a:f6`, Raspi #2 MAC.

Because Discover and Request are broadcast frames, the switch will flood them out of all connected interfaces and Raspi #1 will receive them. It will not receive unicast frames server sends directly to Raspi #2.

If you want to see both ends of the traffic in Raspi #1, you need to [mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) either Raspi #2 port or server's port to the port connecting to Raspi #1.

See [Wikipedia DHCP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)